# Get a list of first names with last name initials if necessary

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, formatting

So in my JS I have an object like so;

```
[
    {
        firstname: "John",
        lastname: "Smith"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Peter",
        lastname: "Gregory"
    },
    {
        firstname: "John",
        lastname: "Fisher"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Sam",
        lastname: "Fisher"
    }
]
```

And I'd like to display the first names in a comma-separated string. Now this would be simple enough, but I also want to display the first initial of the last name only where necessary, to distinguish two people with the same first name.

So, in the end, I'd have this:

```
John S., Peter, John F., Sam
```

Thus far I've been able to do a loop that remembers past initials, but the problem for me becomes the fourth entry in the example; someone with a last name that has had to be distinguished with someone else, but who doesn't a share a first name with anyone.

What would be the smartest way of going about this?

Comment: the smartest way would be to code something first.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/owqc35p3/ come on. Do you need a string as an output too? If you need that as a string, just this http://jsfiddle.net/owqc35p3/1/

Comment: @briosheje That outputs everyone's last initial. I only want them when they're necessary = someone else has the same first name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array.map + Array.join will do it. I included a polyfill for Array.map if you need it at the bottom.

```js
var people = [
{
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Smith"
},
{
    firstname: "Peter",
    lastname: "Gregory"
},
{
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Fisher"
},
{
    firstname: "Sam",
    lastname: "Fisher"
}
]

/* Count number of firstNames */
var firstnames = {};
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
   if (!firstnames[people[i].firstname]) {
       firstnames[people[i].firstname] = 0;
   }
   firstnames[people[i].firstname] ++;
}

/* Create the string of names */
var peopleString = people.map(function (a) {
   /* Check if we need a last name here */ 
   var lastname = firstnames[a.firstname] > 1 ? (a.lastname ? ' ' + a.lastname.substr(0, 1) + '.' : '') : '';
   
   return a.firstname + lastname; 
}).join(', ');

document.write(peopleString);


/*Polyfill for Array.map taken from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill*/
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.19
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19
if (!Array.prototype.map) {

  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| 
    //    value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
    //    method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) 
    //    where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name and 
    //    len is the value of len.
    A = new Array(len);

    // 7. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 8. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
      //    method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
        //    method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal 
        //     method of callback with T as the this value and argument 
        //     list containing kValue, k, and O.
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
        // Pk, Property Descriptor
        // { Value: mappedValue,
        //   Writable: true,
        //   Enumerable: true,
        //   Configurable: true },
        // and false.

        // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
        // Object.defineProperty(A, k, {
        //   value: mappedValue,
        //   writable: true,
        //   enumerable: true,
        //   configurable: true
        // });

        // For best browser support, use the following:
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }

    // 9. return A
    return A;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is though, I only want to display the initial when it is necessary (the two Johns). I don't want it for Peter or Sam, because there's nobody else with the same first name.

Comment: Nice solution, +1 for the polufill and +\ for the clever inline ternary to check whether lastname exists or not. Also, for such a case, you can also use .toString() instead of join, it will work in any case.

Comment: Op wants `Sam F.` to be printed just `Sam`, because no one else has same name.

Comment: Ah shucks. True that. I'll come up with that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I made the changes :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
var o = {};
var arr = [];
people.forEach(function(val) {
    if (!o.hasOwnProperty(val.firstname)) {
       // didn't see this name before,
       // keeping it so we know we saw it
       // and keeping its index, in case we see the same name again
       var idx = arr.push(val.firstname);
        o[val.firstname] = { idx: idx - 1, val: val };

    }
    else {
        // we saw this name, adding the current with a last name
        // also adding last name to the origninal we saved before
        arr.push(val.firstname + " " + val.lastname.substr(0, 1));
        arr[o[val.firstname].idx] = o[val.firstname].val.firstname + " " + o[val.firstname].val.lastname.substr(0, 1);
    }
})
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just if you want an (almost) inline solution...

```
var arr = [
    {
        firstname: "John",
        lastname: "Smith"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Peter",
        lastname: "Gregory"
    },
    {
        firstname: "John",
        lastname: "Fisher"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Sam",
        lastname: "Fisher"
    }
];

var out = arr.map (function(i){
    return arr.filter(function(e){
        return e.firstname == i.firstname && true;
    }, []).length > 1 ? (i.firstname + " " + i.lastname.charAt(0)) : (i.firstname);
}, []).toString();

console.log(out);
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/owqc35p3/2/

It will not be that performant compared to many others though, because we're looping arr every time inside the current arr map (also, `.toString()` can be replaced by `.join(" ,");`)